# How can I delete or download the needed document from folder by a clicking on webpage button?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Let's say the user cannot find the folder in the computer so it is easier to manage the folder files on webpage. I manage to show the folder file documents on webpage/[Here is that webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQk2w.png)/, then I try to download or delete the needed document, but I get some errors.

I try to use os.path.exists() and os.remove() to delete the document, but as I understand I do not create my urls pattern correctly, and do not pass the right argument to my html template.

Here is my code:

## urls.py:

```
....
path('edited_agreements/', views.delete_new_file, name='delete_new_file'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## views.py

```
def new_files_list(request):
    path = MEDIA_ROOT
    new_files_list = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith('.doc') or file.endswith('.docx'):
            new_files_list.append(file)
    return render(request, 'uploads/new_files_list.html', {
        'new_files': new_files_list
    })


def delete_new_file(request, path):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, path)
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.remove(file_path)
    return redirect('new_files_list')
```

## .html

```
....
<tbody>
    {% for new_file in new_files %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ new_file }}</td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="{{ new_file.path }}" target="_blank">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Download</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="{{ new_file }}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
....
```

When I click on delete I want the file to be deleted from  my webpage and from folder, and when I want to download, the file to be downloaded. Now I get the following error:

```
The current path, edited_agreements/222222.docx, didn't match any of these.
```